# Нужна ли запятая перед «и» в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, и

*Рассказываем, что это за материал **и** почему мужчина решился открыть своё дело.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая перед одиночным союзом **и** в этом сложноподчиненном предложении не нужна. Предложение "Рассказываем" является главным в СПП и общим для двух придаточных.

*Рассказываем* [о том], ***что** это за материал и **почему** мужчина решился открыть своё дело.*

> Между однородными придаточными частями сложноподчиненного предложения, связанными неповторяющимися соединительными или разделительными союзами, запятая не ставится: *Отец мой говорил, что он не видывал таких хлебов **и** что нынешний год урожай отличный* (Акс.); *Чудилось, будто корчуют сразу весь лес **и** выдираемые из земли корни и сама земля стонут и вопят от боли* (Фед.) — повторяющихся союзов здесь нет (первый союз *и* соединяет две придаточные части, второй — однородные подлежащие *корни* и *земля*, третий — однородные сказуемые *стонут* и *вопят*)...

*Рассказываем и показываем, **что** происходит в столице Урала и **как** горожане соблюдают введённые ограничения* (из статьи).

[Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении с несколькими придаточными](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827520.html) (§ 35.3)